# Draft Inducer replacement motor part number

Tags: hvac, furnace, electric-motor

The draft inducer motor in my Payne furnace started making a whining sound the other night, so I ordered a replacement from Ebay. My part number is HC21ZE121A, and the motor I got is missing the 'A' at the end. Are they functionally equivalent? Is this just a Carrier vs Payne branding thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a response from the seller, an HVAC technician.

"The 'A' was used by Carrier on some older model motors produced and is irrelevant. The parts produced currently by Carrier/RDC no longer reference this character."